# Forward Only One Port For Proxmox

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, proxmox

I need serious help here, I have no idea how to do this. My idea is that i am only able to forward one port, 443, on my router. Weird, I know, but it's what i have to work with. The issue is that I have 3 services that I need to be able to access through the outside network. I'm hoping to accomplish this with subdomains in some sort of way, so i could have proxmox.example.com go to the management panel for my proxmox server, jellyfin.example.com go to my jelly fin server, etc. Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need a reverse proxy

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possible solutions.

The better one is to use a reverse proxy. Reverse proxies answer all requests and them retrieve the data from other servers/ports.  Apache can do this with Mod_proxy.  (NGINX has something similar and there are ither options as well)

Depending on your use case, you may be ae to set up a VPN on port 443 (UDP is better then TCP but either can work - for exame with OpenVPN).  You would then connevt to the VPN and can access all the resources on your LAN through it.  This has the benefit of increasing security but the downside of requiring a VPN client to access anything.